# Data Binding in autoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-databinding, autocompletetextview

Can anyone help me with data binding in autoCompleteTextView for setting an adapter and getting value in android using java language?
I needed to implement MVVM model architecture in the example, but I am unsure how to do that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I need to know how can I use data binding in autoCompleteTextView in java using MVVM model architecture.